# IdentityServer4 and ASP.NETCore 1.x

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am currently looking at IdentityServer4 as an option for our web services. However, due to corporate compiler level policy, I am only able to use VisualStudio 15.0 which does not support .Net Core 2 (and ASP.NET core 2 therefore). So I am stuck with ASP.Net Core 1.x for the moment. Changing the compiler version is out of the question for the time being.

IdentityServer4 does have a version based on ASP.NEt Core 1.x but doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

**My question is:** Will security vulnerabilities be fixed in Identityserver4 (ASP.NET Core 1.x)? 
The Github repository seemed to be still active 2 months ago. So I am wondering what kind of maintenance will be provided by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security vulnerabilities would be fixed on the 1.x branch - but no more feature work

Answer (score 0):

Here is Brock Allen's answer :

> [...] if there are any security vulnerabilities reported we will fix them. But we won't be adding new features to the ASP.NET Core 1.x branch, as Microsoft themselves have moved on to ASP.NET Core 2.x and (in their eyes) ASP.NET Core 1.x is essentially deprecated.